# How to best update userinfo placed in $rootScope in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am using the Kinvey BaaS that produces an activeUser-object that I store on $rootScope since I need that on most of views in my app.

In the user settings view I want to be able for the user to update his information. But how do I best to that? Can I just set the various input-fields to be bound the the properties on the activeUser object that is on $rootScope? I.e.

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="activeUser.email">
```

Even though it is very common to put auth/session-info on the $rootScope, perhaps there is a better way to do this (regarding updating the user info)? But if I use the normal $scope like this:

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email">
```

How can I get the content of $scope.email to be set to same as the $rootScope.activeUser.email (which might not exist at the very moment the user setting view is opened, only after some milliseconds, depending on how I enter the view)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a watch on `activeUser` in your current scope.

```
$scope.$watch('activeUser', function(newValue,oldValue) {
    if(newValue) {
        $scope.email=newValue.email;
    }
});
```